# Google Directions API restrictions

Tags: google-directions-api

I am developing an app that is using google directions api. But the problem I am facing is that google directions api says:

> The Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited.

But I don't want to show a map, instead I only want to show distance and locations only. But at question [Alternatives to Googles Distance Matrix service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733191/alternatives-to-googles-distance-matrix-service) the guy says that its possible but isn't it against the google restrictions? Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Either display a map (perhaps a small one) or use a different direction finding service that lets you use it the way you want.

Comment: Thanx :) but one more issue is that i want to know that if using a google map can i display all the related information of directions api on other view without showing map on that view?and also does apple maps provide direction services to users as google directions api does?

Comment: Use Mapbox 
https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it's now permissible to use both Directions and Distance Matrix API without a Google Map. Please see the [Google Maps Platform Service Specific Terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/) for the updated terms that applies per each API.

Item 1.1 (for Directions API) and 2.1 (For Distance Matrix API) states:

> Use without a Google Map. Customer may use Google Maps Content from
>   the Directions API  in Customer Applications without a corresponding
>   Google Map.

I hope this helps!